# Is $(\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot)$ a divisible semifield?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

I know that $(\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot)$  is a [semifield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semifield). But I would like to know that whether it is **divisible** with respect to the usual addition and multiplication. Please any idea or help? Thanks.

Comment: $(\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot)$ is a field

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "divisible"? I know what it means for a abelian groups, but not for fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additive group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is divisible: $q \in \mathbb Q, n \in \mathbb N^* \implies q=ny$ for $y=q/n \in \mathbb Q$.

The multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ is not divisible: $2 \in \mathbb Q$, but there is no $y \in \mathbb Q$ such that $y^2=2$.